Review PCB - Lamp and Motors - Round 2
This is a follow-up to this post.
I incorporated the feedback and decided to add a custom DC to DC converter (12V to 3V3). Also I designed the PCB from the schematic.

Traces are 0.3mm by deafult, some 3V3 are 1mm, the thick 12V are 3mm, the 12V going to the motor control are 0.5mm.
Each LED channel is expected to bear max 0.6A, normally just around half of that.
I am planning to use something between 1kHz and 1MHz PWM LED frequency.
caps and resistors are 0603 footprints.
I am using KiCad

I am asking for a review of this new version. The following are some specific questions. However, feel free to comment on anything you like and think might help me :) Thanks a lot!

I will add screw holes.
I still have to decide for connectors J1-J3 and place the footprints accordingly.
Should the traces from the mosfets (Q1-Q5) to J2 be wider?
Should I do some top layer fill?
For the power switcher: I found recommendations for 3x10uF and 1x22uF. 10uF are easier to get - is it fine to just use these? Or should I use a larger version?
With C7-C9, do I still need C10?
The recommended layout for LMR51420Y shows a GND-bride under the chip, as I did. However, a filled zone under the chip did not fill (I guess because of default .5mm clearance), so I manually added a trace (clearence is now min .32mm). Is that ok?
The default filled zone setting is to connect pads with the "thermal relief" pattern (a cross). When is that preferred vs a solid pad connection?
Should RX/TX be a differential pair with tuned lengths? I will use it for programming.




Strange switched EN. It will form a voltage divider and go to 3.3V/2. Gate resistors on your MOSFETs? What’s your motor load? Your 12 V feed to your motor drivers go via skinny tracks and several vias. Same with output.

GPIO0 (BOOT) is always low via R11, so your code will never start.

Motor is JGA25-370. 0.65A up to 2.2A when blocking.

voltage divider: R8=47k, R9=4.7k, so pin is pulled to 0.3V, should be fine with ESP registering low up to ~0.8V. I added R9 to reduce the amp over the button coming from C12

Gate resistors on your MOSFETs: From what I read, it's not necessary with an ESP32, as the internal resistance protects it sufficiently from the load.
